# Why Next.js 13 can't get query params after using `npm run build`?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm using Next.js version 13.4.4 with `pages` folder. I've found out after using `npm run build` I can't get query params in the URL whether with `useRouter` or `useSearchParams` hooks. They are `undefined` or `null`.

Also, I used `force-dynamic` and `use client` in the page I have problem but nothing changed:

```js
import { Box, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function TuitionPayment() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const transId = searchParams.get("trans_id");
  const idGet = searchParams.get("id_get");

  return (
    <>
        <Link
          href={`gymtracker://tuition/${transId}/${idGet}`}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#66A182",
              py: 1,
              px: 2,
              color: "#fff",
              borderRadius: 1,
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">Return to Application</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please share your the full code for your page component

Comment: @RobinThomas I put it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `pages` router, you can simply do:

```
export default function TuitionPayment() {
  const [transId, setTransId] = useState(null);
  const [idGet, setIdGet] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    setTransId(searchParams.get("trans_id"));
    setIdGet(searchParams.get("id_get"));
  }, []);

  if (!transId || !idGet) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
        <Link
          href={`gymtracker://tuition/${transId}/${idGet}`}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
        >
          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "#66A182",
              py: 1,
              px: 2,
              color: "#fff",
              borderRadius: 1,
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">Return to Application</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

It uses the `window.location.search` to retrieve the query params.

---

On a side note, `useSearchParams` is available in `app` router.

---

If you want to use `useRouter`, make sure you use the correct import:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
```

Comment: I can't use `useRouter` to get query params anymore in Next.js?

Comment: @AliBahaari Are you importing `useRouter` from `next/navigation`?

Comment: No, from `next/router`.

Comment: I implemented the code above. It works well in computer but not in Android emulator. I was wondering if you can check my another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77112516/getting-query-params-doesnt-work-with-android-emulator

Comment: Sure, I forgot to tell you thank you for your response and your time.

Comment: I did Thomas. Thanks again.